# What is the difference between TransactionScope and Unit of work in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, unit-of-work

Recently I learned Unit of work in entity framework.Now one question cames in mind is that what is the difference between TransactionScope and unitOfWork layer.I think both are doing same thing.Is it correct?

Answer (score 3):

They are two completely different things. Unit of work is a design pattern or a set of guidelines for how to solve a software problem. TransactionScope is a class that I can use to programmatically define just that, a scope for a transaction.

More info here:

Unit of work - 
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

TransactionScope - https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738523(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Yeah agree...but both are used to manage Transaction and to avoid multiple commit.Is it right??

Comment: @Dnyaneshwar No, that's not true per se. It's not common, but a UoW should not *necessarily* commit its work as one transaction. May it contains stuff that should always be saved even if the (main) transaction fails.

Comment: Transactions are just a way of implementing a unit of work... I think "Completely different things" is wrong. Transactions are an implementation of Unit of Work.

Answer (score 0):

Transactions are an implementation of the design pattern `Unit of Work`.

What we are talking about here is just the level of abstraction.

1. At the top we have `Unit of work` which is applicable to anything.
2. Next, we might have a dot net level abstraction, which would be `Transactions`.
3. Next we have `Entity Framework` which is a dot net repository level abstraction which implements `Transactions`.
4. Finally we have your database `SQL Server` which is wrapped and used by `Entity Framework`

So basically, it is the context. If we are talking in terms of a RDMS we would say `Transaction`. In a dot net context, you can say `Transaction Scope` and in a software design context, it is a `Unit of Work`.